# Downgrade Openssh on RHEL6

Tags: ssh, security, yum, rhel6

Is it ok to downgrade openssh from 5.3 to 4.3 in rhel6 as we are facing compatibility issue between openssh 3.1 client and openssh 5.3 server(SCP file transfer hangs).

Please we cannot upgrade openssh 3.1 due to some other reason.

Regards,
Rehan

Comment: I can think of no good reason to do this. Perhaps you can improve your question by explaining why you want to install old, *known insecure* software in your environment?

Answer (score 10):

I would not recommend downgrading the distribution OpenSSH version shipped with RHEL6. There are dependencies that would potentially break your server. So no, it's probably not okay...

We can possibly help you troubleshoot the client's `scp` issue, though. Have you run the SSH daemon in debug mode? Have you done the same with the client system?

Comment: Previously we have seen this issue and resolve it by degrading to 4.3

Comment: @user176716 That's not a fix. You should try not to move backwards in versions... Fix the client, not the server... if possible.